# Adobe acrobat insert empty page every 30 pages - javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have got a pdf document with 1200 pages. I need to insert an empty page after every set of 30 pages. I am sure this would require javascript since it probably doesn't come as a pre-installed function ?

Thanks appreciate any feedback

Comment: This might help you: https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/inserting-pages-pdf-acrobat-javascript1

Comment: Look at the bottom of this thread too: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1173889?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

You can insert or add a page or pages in a PDF document using the document object's insertPages method. See the "[JavaScript for Acrobat JavaScript Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf)" for more information.